# Switch statement between object types

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to use a switch statement to declare a variable.  The variable will be a different object type based on the case i send.

```
object savedKey = null;
    switch (type)
    {
        case "RegistrationKey":
            savedKey = db.RegistrationKey.FirstOrDefault(k => k.RegistrationKey == key);
            break;
        case "ClockKey":
            savedKey = db.ClockKey.FirstOrDefault(k => k.RegistrationKey == key);
            break;
    }
```

The problem I'm running into is when I try to access the columns in the model I get the message `Cannot Resolve Symbol`

`var decSavedkey = ConCryptor.Decrypt(savedKey.RegistrationKey);`

The registration key can't be found.  If I declare the object type `RegistrationKey savedKey = null;` then I don't receive an error, but the `ClockKey` in my switch statement returns an error because I declared the `RegistrationKey` as the object.

This is how the savedKey is used

```
if (savedKey != null)
        {
            try
            {
                var sentKey = ConCryptor.Decrypt(key);
                var decSavedkey = ConCryptor.Decrypt(savedKey.RegistrationKey);
                var today = DateTime.Now;
                // lets validate some keys
                if (sentKey == decSavedkey && DateTime.Parse(savedKey.ExpirationDate.ToString()) >= DateTime.Parse(today.Date.ToString()))
                {
                    status = true;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                status = false;
            }

        }
```

Comment: Are these two `RegistrationKey` properties of the same type?

Comment: Yes, same type, different table

Comment: And do you finally need only `decSavedKey` or do you need the `savedKey` later?

Comment: I edited my post to show how its used

Comment: I'm assuming you are using Entity Framework. If you only have two cases in your `switch`, then I would just save the property values that you need. You could accomplish this with base types or an interface (as the answers suggest) where the base class has `RegistrationKey` etc, but keep it simple until you can justify added complexity such as inheritance.

Comment: What is `db`? Please provide how you declare it.

Answer (score 0):

You need some common base-class or interface both your classes derive from/implement. As `object` doesn´t know *anything*  about a `RegistrationKey`, your enitities returned from your database should thus be either of type `Class1` or `Class2`:

```
interface MyInterface
{
    List<Key> Keys { get; set;}
}
public class Class1 : MyInterface
{
    public List<Key> Keys { get; set;}
}
public class Class2 : MyInterface
{
    public List<Key> Keys { get; set;}
}
```

Now you don´t need any switch, as the instance itself knows how to resolve `Key`:

```
MyInterface instance = db.QueryFeature(...);
savedKey = instance.Keys.FirstOrDefault(k => k.RegistrationKey == key);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create an interface that declares the common properties of `ClockKey` and `RegistrationKey`:

```
public interface IKeyProps
{
    string RegistrationKey {get;set;}
    DateTime ExpirationDate {get;set;}
}
```

and let the both types implement it:

```
public class RegistrationKey : IKeyProps
{ /*...*/ }
public class CloseKey : IKeyProps
{ /*...*/ }
```

Then declare the `savedKey` variable as `IKeyProps`:

```
IKeyProps savedKey = null;
switch (type)
{
    case "RegistrationKey":
        savedKey = db.RegistrationKey.FirstOrDefault(k => k.RegistrationKey == key);
        break;
    case "ClockKey":
        savedKey = db.ClockKey.FirstOrDefault(k => k.RegistrationKey == key);
        break;
}    

// this now works as IKeyProps declares a RegistrationKey property
var decSavedkey = ConCryptor.Decrypt(savedKey.RegistrationKey);
```

---

Alternativly (if you can't change the class declarations), you could declare `savedKey` as `dynamic`. But then you loose type safety and IntelliSense support etc. And it's rather a hack than a clean solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just change word "object" to name of type of that tables or if types are different change it to "dynamic"

Comment: And what about the `ExpirationDate`?

Comment: Changing the answer

Comment: the tables are of different types, only the `RegistrationKey` columns have the same type

Comment: Please read the question again: "...but the ClockKey in my switch statement returns an error..."

Comment: And how did you guess it means different tables?

Comment: sry, diffent types

Comment: @RenéVogt Added "dynamic" in case types are different)

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing inherently wrong with adding inheritance or an interface to solve this, but I would argue it's not necessary.

Create local variables for the data you will get from each `DbSet` item.

```
string registrationKey = string.Empty;
DateTime expirationDate = DateTime.Min;

switch (type)
{
    case "RegistrationKey":
        var registrationKeyItem = db.RegistrationKey.FirstOrDefault(k => k.RegistrationKey == key)
        if (registrationKeyItem != null)
        {
            registrationKey = registrationKeyItem.RegistrationKey;
            expirationDate = registrationKeyItem.ExpirationDate;
        }
        break;
    case "ClockKey":
        var clockKeyItem = db.ClockKey.FirstOrDefault(k => k.RegistrationKey == key);
        if (clockKeyItem != null)
        {
            registrationKey = clockKeyItem.RegistrationKey;
            expirationDate = clockKeyItem.ExpirationDate;
        }
        break;
}
```

Then call your logic using the retrieved data. Basically, keep it simple.

```
var sentKey = ConCryptor.Decrypt(key);
var decSavedkey = ConCryptor.Decrypt(registrationKey);
var today = DateTime.Now;
// lets validate some keys
if (sentKey == decSavedkey && 
    DateTime.Parse(expirationDate.ToString()) >= 
    DateTime.Parse(today.Date.ToString()))
{
     status = true;
}
```

Comment: if you're going to use `FirstOrDefault` to build `registrationKeyItem`, make sure you handle the null case as well

Comment: That's fair. I always protect against nulls but it should be explicit.